# iOS Settings Bundle with Model

Tags: objective-c, ios, settings

I want to add a Settings Bundle to my application.

This settings bundle should contain multiple network location information objects.

A network information object is:
 - An IP-address
 - An Port Number.

It must be possible to add multiple of these configurations in the settings.

So:

1. A user goes to the preferences.
2. A user adds a new model and fills in the ip/port.
3. A user adds another model.
4. The user launches the application.
5. The applications shows the models.

I rather do not do this in my application.
Is this possible, and if so, how?

**Edit:**
An example is the mail app where you can add accounts.

Comment: what about an array that holds the data, and a navigation controller/table view to render the data ??

Comment: Is that possible in the general settings app? You have a tutorial for that?

Comment: I think you won't find any tutorial covering that precise subject, however, there are many tutorials on how to set up a table views, set up a datasource, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add preferences to the general settings app, you modify a .plist file with specifiers to get the desired effect. After compiling you are not able to modify the contents of the .plist file, as it is part of the application's bundle. So to answer your question, what you want is not possible in the general settings app. However you can still implement it within your app, using for example a .plist in your documents directory, and presemt that in a tableview.